# What's the true differences of these three functions which aim to get the length of an int array?

Tags: c++

I found three solutions online which aims to get the length of a number array. The code is shown below.

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
int GetArrayLength(T (&arry)[N])
{

    return sizeof(arry)/sizeof(T);
}


template<typename T>
int get_array_length2(T& array)
{
    return sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
}


int get_array_length3(int& array)
{
    return sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
}
```

These three solutions, namely `GetArrayLength()` and `get_array_length2()`, both use template as key point and can get right result. However, when I try to write another solution in `get_array_length2()` way namely `get_array_len3()`, an error occurs.

In my opinion, `T& array` is just the same like `int &array`. While the `get_array_length2()` is mainly same as `get_array_len3()` except for template, the results are totally different!

So does the template makes such difference?

Comment: All code must be shown as plain text, inside the question itself, not as an external image. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: I'd be shocked if ether of the last two options work.  Can you show how each of these are being called?

Comment: @StephenNewell [Like this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b15efda69b51dae9)? What do I win?

Answer (score 3):

#### Example 1

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
int GetArrayLength(T (&arry)[N])
{

    return sizeof(arry)/sizeof(T);
}
```

This one is closest to the conventional approach (and to how `std::size` works). It is unclear why the readily-available constant `N` is discarded in favour of `sizeof` antics, though.

---

#### Example 2

```
template<typename T>
int get_array_length2(T& array)
{
    return sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
}
```

This is like your first one, but it doesn't bother spelling out (or enforcing!) an array type, which is kind of fine since you didn't use `N` anyway.

However, there is a risk you could pass a pointer (or other thing supporting `operator[]`) and thereby get incorrect results without realising it. You're pretty much throwing away the whole point of making a nice function template for this task.

If you pass a pointer by mistake, `int*`, then the first example will fail to compile, which is a feature (because you *cannot* determine the size of an array merely from a pointer to its first element).

---

#### Example 3

```
int get_array_length3(int& array)
{
    return sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
}
```

This won't even compile. An `int` cannot be subscripted.

> In my opinion, `T& array` is just the same like `int& array`.

It isn't. If you pass an array (surely the intended usage), your `T` is an array type, like `int[5]` or `int[8]` or `int[42]`. None of these are the same as the type `int`.

---

#### Bootnote

The proper thing to do is to use [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size), or the common spelt-out equivalent, as shown below. Note that this returns a `std::size_t`, not an `int`, so that all possible array sizes are guaranteed to be supported and so that you don't end up trying to compare signed and unsigned values all over the place.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t GetArrayLength(T (&array)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```